# Java Stackoverflow on Debian OS

Tags: java, maven, debian

I am running maven based java test automation framework. When I run this on windows  it runs fine , but when I run on Debian OS , it shows stack-overflow error . Error(few lines snapshot) shown below . Eclipse on windows is 2018-09 and Debian it is -Neon.1a Release (4.6.1). I am using Java SE 1.8 on both. How is it possible that java code works fine on windows but same code throws error on Debian? How do we debug , stackoverflow error ?

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Framework.Framework.run(Framework.java:217)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(ZoneInfo.java:236)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2340)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2312)
    at java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1804)
    at java.util.Calendar$Builder.build(Calendar.java:1508)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CalendarProviderImpl.getInstance(CalendarProviderImpl.java:88)
    at java.util.Calendar.createCalendar(Calendar.java:1666)
    at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1613)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentObservable.collectRunInfo(ExtentObservable.java:441)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentObservable.addLog(ExtentObservable.java:309)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.addLog(ExtentTest.java:359)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.log(ExtentTest.java:308)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest.log(ExtentTest.java:333)
    at Framework.Reporter.ReportError(Reporter.java:231)
    at Framework.Browser$1.initialValue(Browser.java:156)
    at Framework.Browser$1.initialValue(Browser.java:1)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at Framework.Browser.getDriver(Browser.java:172)
    at Framework.Reporter.ReportError(Reporter.java:237)
    at Framework.Browser$1.initialValue(Browser.java:156)
    at Framework.Browser$1.initialValue(Browser.java:1)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at Framework.Browser.getDriver(Browser.java:172)
    at Framework.Reporter.ReportError(Reporter.java:237)
    at Framework.Browser$1.initialValue(Browser.java:156)
    at Framework.Browser$1.initialValue(Browser.java:1)
```

Comment: Is there any recursive method calls in your code?

Comment: No.it work fine on windows

Comment: It looks like the `initialValue()` implementation is self-referential. Are you able to share the code where this method is defined for the `ThreadLocal` accessed by `Framework.Browser.getDriver()`, or is that (!) framework code you do not maintain?